# Windows bug using py utility?

Tags: windows, windows-10, python

`Windows 10`.

1. I've [installed Python 3.11.0](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
2. I've [downloaded yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp).
3. Now it's time to launch yt-dlp. I'm getting weird results in case the first argument to `py` tool does not start from `-`.

Examples. This works fine:

`py -bb "yt_dlp\__main__.py" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=araK9j8mN9Y"`

This does not work:

`py "yt_dlp\__main__.py" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=araK9j8mN9Y"`

Prints nothing. Std error channel prints this:
`Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: ms-windows-store://pdp/?productid=9NJ46SX7X90P`. I can see it using the following command:
`py "yt_dlp\__main__.py" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=araK9j8mN9Y" >out.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Check the very first line of `yt-dlp.py` I'd expect there to be a `!#/usr/bin/python` there, verify that it matches where your python is.

Comment: Is you goal to use yt-dlp to download the linked video? Why not use the [standalone binary](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#recommended) then? If that's not your goal, could you please [edit] your question to include what you want to achieve?

Comment: See [Python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) for how to use it.